# tox is not able to recognize python versions installed by pyvenv

Tags: python, pyenv, tox

I am trying to learn how to use tox for python unit testing on multiple python installations.  I have used `pyenv` to install multiple python installations to the `/home/username/.pyenv/versions/version_number/bin/python`, where `version_number` could be 3.9.16, or 3.10.9.  I have added the following lines to my `pyproject.toml` file.  I have a simple test directory structure that looks like

```
hello
|_ pyproject.toml
|_ hello
|   |_ __init__.py
|   |_ main.py
|_tests
|   |_ __init__.py
    |_ test_main.py
```

Among other lines in my `pyproject.toml` file I have the following `tox` config lines

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = ["tests"]
console_output_style = "progress"

[tool.tox]
legacy_tox_ini = """
    [tox]
    env_list = py39, py310, mypy

    [testenv]
    deps = 
        pytest

    [testenv:py39]
    basepython = /home/jonwebb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/bin/python 

    [testenv:py310]
    basepython = /home/jonwebb/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin/python

    [testenv:mypy]
    deps = mypy
    commands = mypy hello
"""
```

When I try to run tox from the uppermost `hello` directory I get an error stating;

```
py39: failed with env name py39 conflicting with base python /home/username/.pyenv/version/3.9.16/bin/python
py310: failed with env name py310 conflicting with base python /home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin/python
```

It appears that `tox` is having problems with my python installations created with `pyenv`.  How can I fix this installation so it recognizes my python installations installed with `pyenv`?  It is probably worth noting that this code implementation is using a local .venv folder created with `poetry`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `basepython` directives from your `tox.ini`.